# Android App Won't Update To Newer Version After In-App Purchases

Tags: android, google-play

I added in-app purchases in my app. Uploaded to Google Play. Downloaded via Google Play. It was all good. I did purchases, all went well.

But after adding some new features and uploading a new version to Google Play, the existing installed app won't even see that there is an update available.

On a separate phone and a tablet, updated release gets installed just fine.

Seems like after going an in-app purchase, somehow the app on this phone has somehow got locked to its installed version and can't be updated to a newer version.

Why is this happening and how to fix this? I searched online but couldn't find anybody else with this problem.

Comment: How long ago did you update it? If it was within the last 24 hours, I would give it a little more time, as it takes time for updates to show up for all devices.

Comment: it has been 2 months now